# Append node to XML root node using XML Serializer And TextWriter

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmlserializer

Is there any way to append data to an existing XML document using XML serializer.
I am currently doing it like this

```
string filePath = "Data.xml";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Event));
extWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
serializer.Serialize(writer, event);
```

This way adds the element like a root node instead of a child node...I also used LINQ to XML that way worked fine but that's way seems hardcoded.
Is there any way to achieve it using this method.

Comment: Does this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.8) look as relevant solution?

Comment: @pavel that it the way im currently doing it using linq it feels a bit hardcoded that i am looking  for a solution using serializer

Comment: You cannot append to an xml file and get a "Well Formed" xml.  "Well Formed" xml has only one node at the root level.  To append to an xml and get "Well Formed" xml would require removing the closing node.  Using Xml Linq allows add to the middle of an xml (not appending).  I'm not sure why you thing you linq xml solution is "Hard Coded".  Not much different than hard coding classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to manipulate the file without loading it. The Serializers always handle the entire file.

So the right way to do modifications is to Load the File into memory, modify it, and save it again.

For direct anonymous Xml-Node-Level manipulation you should rather use XmlDocument.Load, instead of an XmlSerializer. The XmlSerializer translates the XML into your custom classes first. If you want to add your custom objects, this might be simpler, if you want to Add xml-nodes, you go better with XmlDocument.

Answer (score 0):

If you now the data is at the end of the file

you can open the file by as text 
seek to the end

delete the last row

write the data

and add the last row again

**This is only recommended in case of writing to large uniform files**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append the data using the XmlSerializer, You are better off with using XDocument if you want to add a node to the middle of the XML file. It may look like its "hardcoded" but that is the way to achieve this. As @Holger said the XmlSerializer translates the XML into your custom classes first. You are better off using XmlDocument if you need to add nodes to an already existing XML file.